# How to check if hash comes from a password in hashlib

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

Let's say I have a hash: '013c6889f799cd986a735118e1888727d1435f7f623d05d58c61bf2cd8b49ac90105e5786ceaabd62bbc27336153d0d316b2d13b36804080c44aa6198c533215'

and I suppose that it comes from a password: 'haslo' generated by sha512 algorithm.

How can I check it using hashlib?

I tried converting password into sha512 and then using digest.

```
password='haslo'
password_hash='013c6889f799cd986a735118e1888727d1435f7f623d05d58c61bf2cd8b49ac90105e5786ceaabd62bbc27336153d0d316b2d13b36804080c44aa6198c533215'
converted = hashlib.sha512(password.encode('utf-8'))

if converted.digest() == password_hash.digest():
      return True
else:
      return False
```

But I cant digest password_hash, because it is a string.

Answer (score 2):

`password_hash` is hexadecimal (0x...).
Therefore, you could use `converted.hexdigest()` and convert `converted` to hexadecimal, so that `converted` is the same as `password_hash`

Follow the code below, it return `True`.

```
password='haslo'
password_hash='013c6889f799cd986a735118e1888727d1435f7f623d05d58c61bf2cd8b49ac90105e5786ceaabd62bbc27336153d0d316b2d13b36804080c44aa6198c533215'
converted = hashlib.sha512(password.encode('utf-8'))

if converted.hexdigest() == password_hash:
      return True
else:
      return False
```